# How do I unMount a running function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

I created a stack structure here. As you can see, I made a timer with a Setinterval function in Home.js. The Setinterval function works in Home.js, but it continues to work when I go to the Details page. How can I make it stop when I switch to the Details page?

**Router.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from "./components/Home"
import Details from "./components/Details"
import Other from "./components/Other"
    
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Router= ()=> {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{gestureEnabled:true}} >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Other" component={Other} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Router
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button,StatusBar} from 'react-native';

const Home = ({navigation}) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1);


  useEffect(()=>{
    const myTimer=setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer(timer=>timer+1)
    },2000)

    return ()=>clearInterval(myTimer)
  })

  console.log("timer   :",timer)

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <StatusBar hidden/>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Details.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text,View,Button} from "react-native"

const Details = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Other..."
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Other')}
        />
      </View>
    );
}

export default Details;
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Store the timer in a react ref and `clearInterval(myTimerRef.current)` in the button's `onPress` callback? I guess the trick here may be restarting it upon any back navigation or similar when a user lands back on that screen.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you express it as a code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of using a React ref to hold the timer ref. It can be cleared in the button's `onPress` callback handler. I think a related issue is that the `useEffect` hook hasn't any dependencies and the callback updates state, so it triggers rerenders (though the cleanup function *should* handle this case). Either way, typically when setting up interval timers you only set them up once when the component mounts, clearing the timer when it unmounts.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button,StatusBar} from 'react-native';

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1);
  const timerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => setTimer(timer => timer + 1), 2000)

    return () => clearInterval(timerRef.current)
  }, []); // <-- setup interval only once when component mounts

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <StatusBar hidden/>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Details');
          clearInterval(timerRef.current); // <-- clear interval on navigation
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Got it.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
const intervalRef = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
  const myTimer=setInterval(()=>{
   setTimer(timer=>timer+1)
},2000);

intervalRef.current = myTimer;
return ()=>clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
})
```

Comment: I don't think this will yield the intended behavior. The `return` part of `useEffect` won't be called since Stack Navigation keep the screen alive in the background.